# ASP.NET MVC 4 Client side valiadtion not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am having trouble with MVC 4 client side validation. The form is not validated on the client. Instead it is validated directly on the server.

**Edit**

Model:

```
public class CreateContactFormModel
 {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Vorname")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Nachname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    // Some more properties
}
```

Scripts are loaded properly

Web.config

```
     <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
     <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Input field which I want to validate

```
<input type="text" value="" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" data-val-required="Das    Feld     &quot;Vorname&quot; ist erforderlich." data-val="true" class="form-control">
```

JS Includes

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js">
```

Form code

```
@{
using (Html.BeginForm("CreateContact",
                       "Contacts",
                       FormMethod.Post, 
                        new { id="#contactCreateForm", 
                             @class = "form-horizontal" })){
 .... Form goes here
 }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you load jquery before validate ?

Comment: Are you not using view models ?

please refer [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718004/ASP-NET-MVC-Client-Side-Validation)

Comment: And using any developer tool can you verify all the required scripts are loading properly. ?

Comment: Does the unobtrusive validation not use the `required="required"` attribute?

Comment: @Sam Do you mean I should use [Required="Required"] in my model?

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev no I meant `<input required="required" />`, although I suspect if you are using the MVC helpers to create the `input` it will add the attribute automatically.

Comment: @Sam Yes I am using the helper. As You can see it has added some data attributes.

Comment: Can you force data validations in your cshtml by using

HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;